# How to match curves or measure the similarity between both?

Tags: curve-fitting, calibration, procrustes-analysis

Firstly, I'm not sure whether this is the correct site but I also assume the question is not too different:

Assume there are two curves: One is considered as a reference curve and the other is just an another or "measured" curve.

[image: Example]

I want to transform the measured curve in such a way that it fits the reference curve. In other words: I want to calibrate.

I stumbled over [Procrustes analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis) and [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance) which seem to be usable but nevertheless I wanted to ask you completely unbiased how to proceed. Are there commonly known methods or even implementations in common programming languages (C++, Octave, R,..)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Procrustes doesn't seem like it would be a good fit for this problem because it only allows rigid transformations, reflection, and isotropic scaling. These operations wouldn't be sufficient to get the example curves to match.

Comment: The problem isn't clear to me. Are these curves continuous functions with known expressions, or finite sets of points that have been measured? Should they be treated as y values at a fixed set of x positions, or as parametric curves (x and y values at a fixed set of t positions)? Is the goal to warp one curve to match the other, to measure their similarity, or to match points on one curve to points on the other?

Answer (score 1):

Since Procrustes analysis amounts to iteratively updating a mean (here, a mean curve), I think that is not the suitable in your situation. It is common to use the quadratic Wasserstein distance as a metric in such problems (the literature on this is indeed not so sizeable). The following paper discusses what you may want:
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00749519v2/document

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! I'll have a look on it but however: It seems to be a common problem or task to me so I wonder that there isn't something already implemented? But I'll check it out.